# What is the equivalent of python's _ in javascript?

Tags: javascript, python

In python `_` is used as a [throwaway variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5893946/647991). Is there an idiomatic accepted name in javascript?

Comment: _ is used by the underscore library in JS. So, better to use `dummy` or something else.

Comment: @AJK: ooops, sure, you are right ..

Comment: I've never used a "throwaway variable" - so it'd be a cows opinion

Comment: @JaromandaX: an example here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34628857/647991

Comment: @gonvaled I think you should accept my answer if it answers your question, otherwise this question will remain in the "unanswered" section.

Comment: @Israelg99: yes sure, sorry. You could also upvote my question, since it was interesting enough for you to answer. I wonder why questions get upvoted so rarely, even by people answering them ... A good answer is nothing without a good question :) Anyway, sorry for the short rant. I proceed to accept your answer.

Comment: @gonvaled You are right! people tend to forget to upvote questions, I just did! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't an accepted throwaway variable naming in JavaScript like in Python. 
Although, generally in the software engineering world, engineers tend to call those variables:

**dummy, temp**, trash, black_hole, garbage.

Use these variable namings or whatever name that will imply to the engineer reading your code that these variables have no specific use.

With that in mind, I would strongly not recommend using signs such as below as a throwaway variable:

`_`, `$`

Unless there is an explicit convention like in Python, don't use these signs as a throwaway variable, otherwise, it may interfere with other naming conventions and libraries in other languages, like the underscore and the jQuery libraries in JS.

And of course, if you find a specific use for that variable later on, make sure to rename it.

Answer (score 20):

Rigth now, you can use array destructuring, no need for a var.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

For example:

```
[,b] = [1,2];
console.log(b);
```

will output :

```
2
```

And the value 1 won't be assigned to any unused var.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you will declare the signature of a function as an array. Simply omit one of them

```
const foo = (bar,baz,) => bar+baz;
foo(3,4,5) // → 7
```

This obviously works as long as the declaration of function argument is the last one; unlike [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63374710/891440), which is valid for already-declared variables embedded in arrays. This:

```
const foo = (, bar,baz) => bar+baz;
```

will fail with:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got ','
```

You can hack your way into this using any expression. However, you'll need to use the self same expression in every invocation

```
const quux = ([], bar,baz) => bar+baz;
quux(42,3,4); // → Uncaught TypeError: (destructured parameter) is not iterable
quux([],3,4); // → 7
```

That constant can be anything, so you can as well call it "dummy", but you will still have to repeat in every invocation.