# Accepted practice for an ES6 module imported just for side-effects?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ecmascript-6

I like to keep my code modular, so I put this kind of code in a separate file (`overrides/extra.js`):

```
import Ember from 'ember';

Ember.RSVP.configure('onerror', function(error) {
    ....
});

export default null;
```

This has only the side effect of configuring `Ember.RSVP` but does not export anything of value. I would then import this in `app.js`:

```
import dummy from './overrides/extra';
```

Is this accepted practice?

Comment: No, you're better off just saying `import './foo';`.

Comment: I would export a function doing the configuration instead. Bonus: you can make it return a promise for continuation in the calling code, as you probably *need* to ensure it's done.

Comment: @DenysSéguret: could you show an example of what you mean?

Comment: @gonvaled RGraham pointed to me that the configure function sets an event handler but doesn't seem to be designed to report initialization failures. If it's the case, my point about promise is weak here. I'll precise it in an answer in case it's useful, though.

Comment: @DenysSéguret: I saw the code, and I get what you mean. It's fine as it is now, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes this is *accepted* if your module doesn't need to export any data, but there's no need to export anything from a module if it's not required:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

Ember.RSVP.configure('onerror', function(error) {
    ....
});
```

**app.js:**

```
import './overrides/extra';
```

Answer (score 2):

I usually export an initialization function:

- the calling code is more explicit
- the calling code is able to take action on success (or failure)

I don't know Ember and its initialization but here's how it could look like:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default function initialize(){
    return new Promise(function(ok, nok){
        try { // or any other kind of failure detection
            Ember.RSVP.configure('onerror', function(error) {
                ok();
            });
            ... you may do other initializations here
            ok();
        } catch (e) {
            nok(e);
        }
    });
}
```

In the calling code

```
import initEmber from './yourFile.js';

initEmber()
.then(function(){
    ... here you know Ember is ready
})
.catch(function(){
    ... damn it!
});
```

Note that if Ember initialization is synchronous and may not fail, @RGraham answer may suit you better.

Comment: I know nothing about Ember, but `onerror` looks like a streamed event rather than a one-time thing.

Comment: @RGraham answer updated following your pertinent observation

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tips. In this case, I am reconfiguring the promise system in Ember to display errors on the console whenever a promise rejects, so this is not an error which happens on initialization. So RGraham answer suits me better.